# Not able to display the ModelMap object data in jquery HighCharts

Tags: jquery, spring-boot, jsp, highcharts

'    In My Controller method:
              This below code will return the data with a set of records which contains 3 fields
                   1    Fruits      30 
                   2    Vegetables  40
                  .... and so on
               Here I want to display second and third column in HighCharts graph '

```
   List<Object[]> vendingTypesCount = svService.getVendingTypeWiseVendorsCount();
       Map<String,Object> mp = new LinkedHashMap<String,Object>();   // mp is LinkedHashMap object
       for (Object[] objects : vendingTypesCount) {
          mp.put(objects[1].toString(), objects[2]);           
       }   

      // checked in Java, data is getting accessed perfectly

      map.addAttribute("vendingTypesData",mp);   // here map is the ModelMap object
```

// In my Jsp:

```
 <figure class="highcharts-figure">
    <div id="container2"></div>
    <p class="highcharts-description">        
    </p>
   </figure>


   <script type="text/javascript">
    Highcharts.chart('container2', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Vending Types Data '
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: [[${vendingTypeData.keySet()}]],         // data not getting accessed,
        crosshair: true
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Number of Vendors'
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
        pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
            '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f} mm</b></td></tr>',
        footerFormat: '</table>',
        shared: true,
        useHTML: true
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            pointPadding: 0.2,
            borderWidth: 0
        }
    },
    series: [[${vendingTypeData.values()}]]           // data is not getting accessed
  });
```

Comment: Hi @seshu kumar, You have used highcharts tag, but the problem doesn't seem to be about a chart - rather about data. If you'll have problems with Highcharts then please provide a demo with hard-coded, exemplary data.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm able to access the data from database and checked in the console as well.  It's displaying.  After getting the values in the form of object array, I'm storing in the map in the form of key-value pairs.  That code everything I've provided.  Please help

Comment: In the figure part, the chart has to be displayed.  I've given the id as container2

Comment: So what is the result of `[${vendingTypeData.values()}]` ?

Comment: when it's displaying in console it's coming with three columns from database

Comment: id   vendingType   count

Comment: 1   Vegetables    5  etc......on the top the page I've written comment about how I'm getting data from database

Comment: please check if your series and data structure is correct: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.data